# How to use jQuery localStorage to remember last opened tab?

Tags: jquery, tabs, local-storage

I am having an issue with tabs being remembered after the page is refreshed/reloaded. In a couple of tabs there is a form that gets submitted, when the user is returned to the page the tab goes back to default tab rather than the one that they had previously opened. This is the issue, I need to be able to remember which tab was open and have it remain open.

The HTML I am using is as follows:

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab 1</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab 2</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab 3</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab 4</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-5">Tab 5</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
  content 1 here
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
  content 2 here
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
  content 3 here
</div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
  content 4 here
</div>
<div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">
  content 5 here
</div>
```

The jQuery is am using is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).index() + 1;
    });

});

if (localStorage.selectedTab) {
    var tb = localStorage.selectedTab;
    $("tab-link:eq(" + (localStorage.selectedTab - 1) + ")").click();
  alert (tb);
}
```

As you can see I have set up an alert which tells me the information is being stored in localStorage and I can retrieve it this way. The problem is with this line of code:

```
$("tab-link:eq(" + (localStorage.selectedTab - 1) + ")").click();
```

The tab isn't being remembered after refresh, any help would be greatful as to where I am going wrong.

Here is a link to the current working code: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhonms8L/)**

Comment: Move your code inside of the `ready` block and fix a typo in your selector, it should be `".tab-link:eq(..)"` instead of `"tab-link:eq(..)"`.

Comment: @msg Thank you for that, it's much appreciated. It's now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).index() + 1;
    });

 if (localStorage.selectedTab) {
    var tb = localStorage.selectedTab;
    var tab = "li.tab-link[data-tab='tab-" + tb + "']";
    $('li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(tab).addClass('current');
    alert(tb);
}
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t9so1fy4/5/